# Mudblazor Datagrid hide the Click Icon when Filtering date only

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I have the following code

```
<MudDataGrid Items="@_items">
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.JoinedDate" Title="JoinedDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Filterable="true" />

    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>

@code {

    public record Model (string Name, DateTime JoinedDate);

    ObservableCollection<Model> _items = new ObservableCollection<Model>()
    {
        new Model("Sal", new DateTime(2005, 3, 5)), 
        new Model("Ben",  new DateTime(2010, 1, 17)) 
    };
}
```

I want to be able to filter the JoinedDate by the date only. I do not want the clock item to appear in the filter, the clock icon in the filter is for time only. I do not want the clock to appear because it uses real estate on the page and is not required, I only want to be able to filter using the data (the calendar Icon)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not yet possible with MudBlazor.

But there is an open enhancement issue that suggests exactly this including a workaround to hide it:

https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/7741

So according to the workaround description, simply hiding it using CSS has a downside, because of a flexbox creating an empty space, but I think doing more work than a Pullrequest would take and waiting for a release is not worth it.